# Simple Move Files in AppleScript

Tags: file, applescript, move

I poked around and did find code that works but I can't figure out why my simple version didn't work and the more complicated did:

This code does not work, results in error

> "Can’t get entire contents of "Macintosh HD:Users:Andrew:Downloads"."

```
tell application "Finder"

    move entire contents of DownloadsFolderAddress to StatementFolderAddress

end tell
```

But this code DOES work??

```
tell application "Finder"

    set AllStatementsList to get every item of (entire contents of folder DownloadsFolderAddress)

    move AllStatementsList to StatementFolderAddress

end tell
```

Very curious why the second example works and not the first

Comment: I should note that the address variables are all HFS, "Macintosh HD:blah:blah:blah" so I know that is not a factor

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: You cannot get the contents of a **literal string**.

The second example works because you specified a `folder`.
Sometimes the Finder can infer the type but it's good practice to specify it always.

Assuming `StatementFolderAddress` is also the HFS path to a folder

```
tell application "Finder"
   move entire contents of folder DownloadsFolderAddress to folder StatementFolderAddress
end tell
```

Comment: Jeez. I knew it had to be easy. Thank you, that did in fact work.